# display in console the time of a stop watch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the stop watch code in the link below

[Stop Watch Codes](https://jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/r3su6b6n/)

Here the additional codes I have created

```
<h1 id="lapping"><time></time></h1>
<button type="button" id="lap" class="btn btn-default">Lap</button>
```

and here is the additional JQuery I created

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var testValue = $("#lapping").text();

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#lap").click(function() {
            console.log(testValue);
        });
    });
});
```

I need some help on my Lap `onclick` code since it always displays 00:00:01 on the console even if I click on the Lap button at 20 secs or 1 minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only read the `#lapping` value when the DOM loads. Instead you need to retrieve that value whenever the `#lap` button is pressed.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lap").click(function() {
        var testValue = $("#lapping").text();
        console.log(testValue);
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r3su6b6n/251/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are fetching the value on DOM ready event and never updating the variable `testValue`, it will also display its initial value i.e.`00:00:01`

You need to re-fetch the value whenever you click on the `lap` element .

*Use*

```
$("#lap").click(function() {
    console.log($("#lapping").text());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/d53oahuo/)